# Why to reduce code and only have functions called once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain why the two code snippets are not the same?

The first is the correct one,

```
if (coolDownTimer.read() === 0) {
  alert()
  if (errorCoolDownPeriod > 0) {
    await coolDownTimer.start()
  }
} else if (coolDownTimer.read() >= errorCoolDownPeriod) {
  alert()
  coolDownTimer.reset()
}
```

but I don't like having `alert()` written twice, so since `errorCoolDownPeriod` is a positive number, I figured I could do

```
if (coolDownTimer.read() > 0) {
  alert()
    if (coolDownTimer.read() === 0) {
//      alert()
      if (errorCoolDownPeriod > 0) {
        await coolDownTimer.start()
      }
    } else if (coolDownTimer.read() >= errorCoolDownPeriod) {
//      alert()
      coolDownTimer.reset()
    }
}
```

but they don't behave the same, when I test it.

## Question

Why do the two code snippets not behave the same?

Comment: Well `coolDownTimer.read() > 0` and `coolDownTimer.read() === 0` look like they are incompatible conditions.

Comment: Yes, for some reason, but I don't understand why.

Comment: `if (coolDownTimer.read() > 0) ... if (coolDownTimer.read() === 0)` will never enter the second condition, since if it entered the first condition, the value of `coolDownTimer.read()` is such that it can never fulfil the second condition.

Comment: Are you serious ? Can a number be both zero and nonzero ?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting because a value can not be `n === 0 && n > 0`  at the same time

Comment: Maybe each time `coolDownTimer()` is called gives different values ?

Comment: A number equal to zero will never be greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, `alert()` is executed when `coolDownTimer.read() === 0` or `coolDownTimer.read() >= errorCoolDownPeriod`.

A correct refactoring is:

```js
const timer = coolDownTimer.read();
if (timer === 0 || timer >= errorCoolDownPeriod) {
  alert();
  if (timer === 0 && errorCoolDownPeriod > 0) {
    await coolDownTimer.start()
  } else if (timer !== 0) {
    coolDownTimer.reset()
  }
}
```

More is possible is you have particular restriction on the values, for example i suppose that all the values are real-time timers, so contains only positive values.

Comment: you mean because of this `const timer = coolDownTimer.read()` ?

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas' comment to OP explains the issue. You can't have `n === 0 && n > 0`, so to only have `alert()` called once, you should do

```
if (coolDownTimer.read() === 0 || coolDownTimer.read() >= errorCoolDownPeriod) {
  alert()
    if (coolDownTimer.read() === 0) {
//      alert()
      if (errorCoolDownPeriod > 0) {
        await coolDownTimer.start()
      }
    } else if (coolDownTimer.read() >= errorCoolDownPeriod) {
//      alert()
      coolDownTimer.reset()
    }
}
```

Ie. Take each of the conditions and OR them in the new outer if-statement.

Comment: @Sandra And I would argue that repeating the conditions is actually less clean the repeating the `alert()`. If the `alert()` is actually a larger snippet, it might make sense to extract it into a helper function so that you could really just call it twice.